# git plugin not showing up in list of installed plugins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I kept the extracted plugin under

```
/var/lib/jenkins/plugins
```

And also restarted the server.

Anything else I need to do ?

Comment: Check your Jenkins log for errors loading the Git plugin - feel free to post here with any follow up questions.